# Unable to get the absolute value of command output

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal, sh

So I wanted to make a simple script to keep checking the CPU temperature of my RasPi, which is stored in `/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp` , and hence `cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp` would give the temp, but like this :

```
cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp
38459
```

which essentially means 38.459 degree Celsius.

I was unable to format the output to get 38.594 °C

My code:

```
tempT="$(cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp)"
tempC=$($tempT / 1000)
echo "$tempC °C"
```

The error I get:

```
-bash: 38459: command not found
 °C
```

Thanks

Comment: `$($tempT / 10)` -> `$((tempT / 10))`. But "dividing by 10" is not a absolute value. Do you want the [absolute value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value) or do you want to solve the error or do you want to print the value with 3 digits after comma? What is exactly your question?

Comment: Yeah I want to print the value with the last 3 digits behind the decimal. And also changing it to `$((tempT / 1000))` gives me
`-bash: tempT: command not found °C`

Comment: [How do we ask a good question on stackoverflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Is the sensor even *accurate* to 3 decimal places, and do you actually need that level of precision? `tempC=$((tempT/1000))` would let you distinguish between 38 °C and 39 °C (though the result is always rounded towards 0, not the nearest integer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest would be to use `awk`.

```
awk '{print $1/1000}' /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp
```

or with some more control with printf

```
awk '{printf "%.3f\n", $1/1000}' /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp
```

The error you are seeing comes from that you used `$( ...)`, which is a command substitution and tries to run the command inside. So when you do:

```
$($tempT / 1000)
```

First `$tempT` expands to 38459 and then shell tries to run a command named `38459` with two arguments `/` and `1000`. So you see the message `38459: Command not found`. Use `$((...))` for arithmetic expansion, but shells do not implement floating point arithmetic so you have to use other tools like `awk` or `bc`.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use bc if it is available on your system.

```
$ CELSIUS=$(bc -l <<< $(cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp)/1000)
$ echo $CELSIUS 
25.00000000000000000000
```

Comment: It should be, as `bc` is part of the POSIX specification.

Answer (score 1):

```
TempC=$($tempT / 1000);
```

Resolves to:

```
TempC=$(38459 / 1000);
```

And bash treats `$(...)` as a command to be passed into a subshell, so it tries to run the executable `38455`, which it can't find, and hence complains.

I would use `bc`, as @kinezan suggested, though I personally prefer the following convention:

```
TempC=$(echo "scale=3; $tempT / 1000" | bc)
```

which outputs `38.459`